# Does "a media work" make sense?

Tags: word-usage

There is a genre of art called new media art or media art. What do you think about the expression "I created a media work"?

Edit:
If "I created a media work" is incorrect, what is a correct way?

Answer (score 1):

All art is created through **the medium** of something or other, whether drawing, painting, sculpture, video or anything else.

This to say that **I have created a media work** is really a bit vague and self evident.

There's a complication to this however. **Media** was once the plural of **medium** but the word has now been reduced by popular usage to the singular and has taken on new meanings. So we constantly here that **social media plays...** or **the news media is....**.

I can't speak for the genre of art that you refer to as **new media art** (even though visitors to art galleries are these days bombarded with sound scapes and video creations).

Assuming that the genre you refer to is recognised, you could speak of creating **a new media work** But this is ambiguous. It's hard to know whether the word **new** qualifies **media** or **work**.

So you'd be safer avoiding it and resorting to a description such as **A work (created) in new media**, at least until the expression **new media** becomes idiomatic among those outside artistic circles.

Answer (score 1):

"I created media art" or "I create media art" might be better as this describes the type of art you have created, and that you create.

If I had produced some digital graphic art and I wanted to ask someone to take a look at it, I might say, "I created digital graphic art, here, come take a look and see what you think?".

Same for media art.  "I created media art, please share your thoughts on this magical creation...".

Answer (score -1):

> I created a media work

Doesn't really scan, "work" on it's own is rarely used to indicate an individual - you would use "works" for a collection, the genre doesn't really matter (although in some cases you would be able to decipher the intended meaning from context). You can see the same if you say

> I created an impressionist work

This doesn't scan either whereas this does:

> I created a series of impressionist works

Instead you would use "piece" or "artwork" to indicate the singular so:

> I created an impressionist artwork

in your particular case since the genre ends in the term "art" while it would be *technically* correct to say

> I created a "media art" artwork

it's inelegant to say (and to a lesser extent read) so you'd say:

> I created a "media art" piece

instead. The quotation marks (when written) are helpful for parsing the "media art" as a single term made up of two words, when saying it either a slight change of inflection on the words or a very slight pause before saying piece would have the same effect.